# Can we merge the tags [hardcode], [hardcoded] and [hard-coding]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I think the tags [hardcoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardcoded), [hardcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardcode) and [hard-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-coding) all means basically the same thing.

I suggest we merge them all into the tag [hardcoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardcoded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have synonimized them for now.

Answer (score 10):

Why is this a tag at all?  I would want to explore this qualifying as a tag at all before merging it.

Comment: I'm dubious as well; but with the burnination process at a standstill is there any harm in sweeping all three piles of trash together?

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight that people feel that a bigger pile is harder to deal with, so nothing happens.